# Laravel-Array input can not be updated in database

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table called Orders has one to many relationship with orderItems table when I want to update the 
Array values of orderItems table it shows me this  Error Exception Array to string conversion and the values do not update in the database
although when I use the dd() function it shows me all the array inputs 
This my view (order-form)

```
@if(count($orders)>0)
 @foreach ($orders as $order)
<form action="{{route('order.update',$order->id)}}" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="PUT" name="_method"/>
        @csrf
    <input name="cus_name" type="text"  value={{$order->customerName}}><br/>
    <input name="cus_address" type="text" value="{{$order->customerAddress}}"><br/>
    <input name="order_date" type="date"  value="{{$order->orderDate}}"><br/>  
 @if(count($orderItems)>0)
  @foreach ($orderItems as $orderItem)
    <input name="productName[]" type="text" value="{{$orderItem->ProductName}}"><br/> 
    <input name="Quantity[]" type="number"  value="{{$orderItem->Quantity}}"><br/>
    <input name="price[]" type="number"  value="{{$orderItem->price}}" ><br/> 
   @endforeach
  @endif
    <button type="submit" >update </button>                    
</form>
```

And this is my orderController

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $order_Data  = Order::where('id',$id)->update([
        'customerName' => $request->input('cus_name'),
        'customerAddress' => $request->input('cus_address'),
        'orderDate'  => $request->input('order_date')
    ]);
    $data=array();
    foreach ($request->productName  as $key => $value) {
            $data[]=[
                'ProductName' =>$value,
                'Quantity'    =>$request->Quantity[$key],
                'price'       =>$request->price[$key],
                'OrderID'=>$id
            ];          
    }
  //dd($data);
    OrderItem::where('id',$id)->update($data);
    return redirect(route('order.index',$id));
}
```

The error appears in this line

```
OrderItem::where('id',$id)->update($data);
```

I tried to

- use save() method but it does not work
- use `'ProductName'    =>$request->productName[$key]` instead of
  `'ProductName' =>$value` but also does not work

I want to get as this result when press update botton

> Order 1=[
>            { Product 1,qty1,price 1},
>            { Product 1,qty1,price 1},
>           {…….}
>                  ]

Anyone can help me I will be so glade

Answer (score 0):

Try this once.

```html
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $order_Data  = Order::find($id);
        $order_Data->customerName => $request->input('cus_name');
        $order_Data->customerAddress => $request->input('cus_address');
        $order_Data->orderDate  => $request->input('order_date');
  $order_Data->save();
       $order_Data->order_items()->delete();
  
   
    $data=[];
    foreach ($request->productName  as $key => $value) {
          
                $order_items = new OrderItem;
    $order_items->ProductName = $request->get("ProductName")[$key]);
                $order_items->Quantity = $request->get("Quantity")[$key]);
                $order_items->price = $request->get("price")[$key]);
                
                $order_items->save();
    return redirect(route('order.index',$id));
}
```

Comment: But instead of updating the values

Comment: It insert new values do you have another idea to solve it

Comment: But instead of updating the values ??

Comment: Instead of updating the values in the database it insert new records to the database

Answer (score 0):

**01. use json_encode() method**

```
$data = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks but when I tried this an error apeared such as object of class stdclass can not be converted to string